# How to use the malloc() function for char string/array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I'm writing a code that reads in a list of characters (using redirection), but the string I'm storing the characters to has a size of 41. The number of characters do not come close to the size of the array, therefore I need to use malloc() in order to get the exact array size. When I print the array without using the malloc function is prints symbols and other gibberish along with the string. I need to malloc the string so the symbols and gibberish won't be included.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char c;
    char r1[41];
    int a = 0;

    while(scanf("%c", &c) != EOF) {
        if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c == '[' || c == '.' || c == '!') {
        r1[a] = c;
        a++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe string is: %s\n", r1);

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The string is TR[!.DFQ▒ ▒ ▒ 這
```

Comment: Your `string` is an array of 42 pointers to `char`. You want `char string[40+1];`. (And of course you'll need to store some value in it.)

Comment: There is nothing in that code that reads any value(s) in from anywhere. Thus the contents of your `string` array are uninitialized, which leads to further undefined behavior...

Comment: Any reason why you're not using C++? With the string class you won't need to malloc anything.

Comment: @iab: Why not also ask why OP isn't using OCaml or Ruby?

Comment: I'm in a computer science class in college that is strictly C programming.

Comment: @iab I could enumerate at least five reasons off the top of my head why I would use C and not C++...

Comment: @R Because he's doing C and C++ is basically a superset of C?

Comment: @H2CO3 I bet you could. But string handling, as in this particular case, is reason enough why the OP could consider using C++ instead.

Comment: @Tom Murphy I didn't know you're limited to using C - that's OK :-).

Comment: @iab naw, C is not even close to being a subset of C++. At all.

Comment: @iab To clarify with H2CO3's comment... Once upon a time, C was pretty much a subset of C++ (but even then it wasn't exactly). These days, however, the best you can say I think is that there is a subset of C that is also a subset of C++.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of points of confusion mixed together here.

1. The reason your code is printing gibberish isn't due to fixed-length vs. variable-length. Switching to malloc() won't fix that problem. Make sure you have a null terminator (`'\0'`) at the end of the string:

   ```
   while(scanf("%c", &c) != EOF) {
       ...
   }

   r1[a] = '\0';
   ```
2. Your original code mixed array and pointer syntax. For a single string you should use either `char[]` or `char*` but not both.

   For a fixed-size string, declare it as:

   ```
   char string[40+1];
   ```

   For a variable-length string, do:

   ```
   char *string = malloc(length + 1);

   if (string == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   // memory allocation successful
   ```

Comment: I was using the declaration: char string[40+1] at first. I think it will be best if I show my entire code.

Comment: I debugged the program plenty of times, when I used the exact size of the array, the symbols and gibberish didn't print. So it is the extra indexes that causes the symbols and gibberish.

Comment: @TomMurphy No, it isn't. It's the undefined behavior caused by the missing NUL-terminator. Be humble, don't try to be smarter than the person who pointed out and solved your obvious beginner mistake.

Comment: Thanks this works. My professors told me that I must allocate the memory for the string in order to get it to print correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *string[40+1];
```

This defines `string` as an array of 41 pointers to `char`. If you want it to hold a string, you'll want to define it as:

```
char string[40+1];
```

If you know (at run time, but not at compile time) how long the string will be, you can use `malloc` -- but you'll want to assign the result to a single pointer of type `char*`:

```
char *s = malloc(len + 1);
if (s == NULL) {
    /* malloc failed, handle the error */
}
```

This causes `s` to point to the first (0th) element of an array of `char`. That array is uninitialized, so you'll need to copy some data into it.

Once you've done that, and assuming the contents are properly null-terminated, *then* you can print the string's value using:

```
printf("The string is: \"%s\"\n", string);
```

The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is an excellent resource for this kind of thing.